# JavaFX Tab collapses when icon gets over 22.0 width/height

Tags: javafx, icons, tabpanel

At 22.0 height

[image]

How to avoid this result when the ImageView height gets over 22.0?

[image]

I´m not using css at all. I founded this Bounds thing in the layout dropdown menu from the ImageView, which is not even editable, that 22x22 seems to be maximum dimension or something, I tried changing Tab min height but it´s the same issue.

[image]

```
<TabPane fx:id="tabs" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" tabMinHeight="50.0" tabMinWidth="150.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <tabs>
      <Tab fx:id="tabProd" text="TEXT" closable="false">
        <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="40.0" fitWidth="40.0">
                <image>
                    <Image url="framesFX_icons/production.png" />
                </image>
            </ImageView>
        </graphic>
           <content>
              ...
           </content>
      </Tab>
    </tabs>
  </TabPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `tabMaxHeight` to something large (but lower than `Double.MAX_VALUE`) seems to solve it, so I'm guessing it's a bug?

Anyway - setting the max height to something like 100 or so should probably be enough.

Edit: The bug report can be found [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161051)